# Comparing typographic traditions for different languages

Tags: typography, languages

Sometimes students using LaTeX ask me how to do the typesetting of documents in French or Spanish.  I'm not able to help them because I never learned to speak or write French or Spanish.

Different languages have different typographic rules to typeset documents. For English documents one can read Robert Bringhurst's "The Elements of Typographic Style" or for German documents, for example, "Detailtypografie" by Friedrich Forssman and Ralf de Jong.

Do you know a document (book, article or URL) comparing the styles for some languages (English, German, French, ...)?

For example:

- abbreviations are written in German with `\,` (`z.\,B.` = e.g.), in English without any space,
- a dash in English is `---` without spaces before and after the character, in German `~--` (with spaces),
- the quotation marks are different (“Foo” vs. „Bar“ vs. « Baz »; package `csquote`),
- vertical, horizontal and double rules in tables (package `booktabs`),
- in German the ampersand & is only allowed in company names (Paul & Söhne), in English ?
- there are different style formatting footnotes in German (e.g. normal number, hanging, footnote text left justified or right left justified). Other languages?

Comment: Your comment about the em dash in English isn't wholly correct. I think OUP insists on em-dash (i.e. `---`) but other sources allow or recommend the en dash (i.e. ` -- ` ). I don't have Bringhurst to hand, but I think he's ok with en dashes.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In French, try [www.guide-typographie.com](http://www.guide-typographie.com/), which includes a section comparing English typography. For more on French typography, see [www.synapse-fr.com/typographie/TTM_0.htm](http://www.synapse-fr.com/typographie/TTM_0.htm). Also check the collections of links at [tex.loria.fr/english/typographie.html](http://tex.loria.fr/english/typographie.html) and, of course, the many treasures at [jacques-andre.fr](http://jacques-andre.fr/).

Comment: There is also the *Lexique des règles typographiques en usage à l'Imprimerie Nationale*, which is the official reference for French language, and [Lacroux's excellent book](http://www.orthotypographie.fr/).

Answer (score 19):

If you are using [`biblatex`](http://tug.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) with [`biber`](http://biblatex-biber.sourceforge.net/) as back-end for citations, [`csquotes`](http://tug.ctan.org/pkg/csquotes) for quotations, and [`babel`](http://tug.ctan.org/pkg/babel) for language support, you are half way to your goal. :-)

If you are typesetting units, [siunitx](http://tug.ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) will help you to the correct notation (see also the web page of [*Bureau International des Poids et Messures*](http://www.bipm.org/en/si/)). However, the SI-notation is not always ‘correct’ typography.

For the details regarding specific language, I suggest that you ask questions, for example on `tex.sx`.

I can give some references to Norwegian typography, but since the articles and web pages are in Norwegian, I assume they will be of use for only a limited audience. For general typography, see for example the web pages [Typografi.no](http://www.typografi.no/pages/nettsted/default.aspx) and [Typografi i Norge](http://www.typografi.org).  Very interesting is the link to fourteen (14) articles by the Norwegian typographer [*Sven Erik Skarsbø*](http://www.typografi.org/norsk_paa_trykk/norsk_paa_trykk.html). The articles are in full text (.PDF-files in Norwegian), and answer most of your questions regarding Norwegian language and Norwegian typography.

The text book used at typographical schools in Norway, [Øyvin Rannem: *Bokstav, bilde, budskap : lærebok i typografi*](https://bokelskere.no/bok/bokstav-bilde-og-budskap-en-laerebok-i-typografi/44030/), is available online free for non-commercial use at the [University Library](https://www.nb.no/items/1520a184f5395cf7da0639a18d07beee;page=0;searchText=?page=0), *provided you have a Norwegian IP address*.

This book is one they are using at the education institute for typographers and graphic designers:

```
@book{rannem_bokstav_1988, 
  address = {Oslo}, 
  title = {Bokstav, bilde, budskap : lærebok i typografi}, 
  isbn = {978-82-00-35138-2}, 
  publisher = {Universitetsforl.}, 
  author = {Rannem, Øyvin}, 
  year = {1988}, 
  keywords = {} 
}
```

Answer (score 15):

In Germany we have many rules which are written down in a standard called DIN (deutsche Industrie Norm - german industry standard ). Those rules are typographic rules in some way  while  not necessarily developed by typographers.

There is a standard about citations: DIN 1505-2 [Wikipedia (german)](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/DIN_1505-2)

It says basically :
 `Name1, Prename1[ ; Name2, Prename2 ; ...]: Title : Subtitle.
[Volume ]Place: Publisher,
Year.[ - ISBN #####][ p. #-#]`

Another rule defines Symbols: DIN 1302 [Wikipedia (german)](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/DIN_1302) or formular symbols (this is compatible to  SI) [DIN 1338](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/DIN_1338) . I could link many more cause we have standards for every situation ;)

The international equivalent is [ISO 80000](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_80000) which defines also typographic rules for typesetting units etc.

Another good source for information about unit typesetting is btw the `siunitx` documentation.

Comment: Good hint with package siunitx; The german DIN is usefill for german or german speaking people. Do you know a simular Document for Frensh, Spanish, ... ?

Comment: *we have many rules which are written down in a standard called DIN*.  That is **soo** German.

Answer (score 11):

The [German Wikipedia article on quotation marks](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anf%C3%BChrungszeichen#Andere_Sprachen) provides a great table comparing styles from many countries. It's just a partial solution, but it might be a start.

Comment: or for the English-speaking people, a [similar table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark#Summary_table_for_various_languages) can be found in the English Wikipedia!

Answer (score 11):

There is also an *excellent* reference for Tex in Spanish, discussing typographic traditions and lots of related items. http://www.tex-tipografia.com by Javier Bezos, who is also the author of several popular LaTeX packages.

Answer (score 10):

For french, the definite guide is the recently published [Orthotypographie](http://www.orthotypographie.fr/). There is also the guide that is used by the [Imprimerie Nationale](http://www.amazon.fr/Lexique-r%C3%A8gles-typographiques-lImprimerie-Nationale/dp/2743304820).

However, none of these guides contain concrete LaTeX suggestions. I presume that most of the typographic elements that are used in LaTeX standard packages have been transcribed by the Babel or similar packages.

To the best of my knowledge, there is no comparative guide across various languages.

Answer (score 10):

The reference for French is the *Lexique des règles typographiques en usage à l'Imprimerie Nationale*. `frenchb` (French `babel`) implements quite a few of these rules, and the `impnattypo` package provides more of them.

Comment: What do you mean by "follows"?

Comment: No it isn't. They've existed side-by-side for years, and `e-french` was (to my knowledge) a paid package (sic). I keep using `frenchb` since I have yet to this day to get a propre explanation of why I should switch to `e-french`...

Answer (score 5):

For Russian typographical traditions there is a short article by V. Zaitsev et al. "Russian Typographical Traditions in Mathematical Literature". It is not a comprehensive guide, still it highlights a number of differences from vanilla LaTeX `article` style.

It is available from http://www.uni-giessen.de/partosch/eurotex99/zaitsev.pdf.

Comment: The link perhaps should be http://www.staff.uni-giessen.de/partosch/eurotex99/zaitsev.pdf

Comment: @BenjaminMcKay Both links are gone as of now :-(. Any edit?

Comment: At the moment, it seems to be available only on citeseerx: https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/document?repid=rep1&type=pdf&doi=c109d773ef8651eb6a709393a21f79e850920892

Answer (score 3):

For an introduction (in German) to the use of Chinese, Japanese and Korean characters as well as the Japanese and Korean syllable-based writing systems, I recommend:

Zippel, Susanne: [Fachchinesisch Typografie](https://typografie.de/produkt/fachchinesisch-typografie/) (ISBN 978-3-87439-818-3).

Its focus lies on **Chinese**, and it includes a comparison to German typography as well as a multilingual glossary of typographic terminology (Chinese, German), and an illustrated explanation of the structure of CJK characters and the two syllabic Japanese writing systems.
The book also offers advice on when to use which character style (*mingti* 明体 / *heiti* 黑体 / *kaishu* 楷书).

Answer (score 2):

For Italian, the reference about typographic traditions and their use in LaTeX is the paper "[Norme tipografiche per l'italiano in LaTeX](https://www.guitex.org/home/images/ArsTeXnica/AT001/norme%20tipografiche%20per%20litaliano%20in%20latex.pdf)" by Gustavo Cevolani, published in the first issue of [ArsTeXnica](https://www.guitex.org/home/arstexnica).